# Simple Unix question - Configure

Tags: solaris, ksh

I'm using Solaris 10, [ksh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korn_shell).  Whenever I do a `./configure`, I get the error "ksh: ./configure: not found"

When I do a "where configure", nothing is found.

How do I "install configure"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to run a command for another directory; and then that popped everything up :)

In case someone else comes across this specific issue, I'm trying to install the Perl-Php plugin on a Solaris machine.  Initially, there is no configure file; instead you have to find where your "phpize" is located -- for me it was /opt/webstack/php/5.2/phpize, run it while you are still in the "perl-php-plugin" folder, and then configure will appear.

Then you can ./configure :)

Thanks to everyone who responded.

Comment: FYI, these details would have helped in the original question.

Comment: I initially thought that configure was a built in system command.

Answer (score 5):

`./configure` means that you want to run an executable called `configure` in your current directory (signified by a `.`). I'm guessing you're trying to build and install from source, and the directions say to do the standard `./configure; make; make install`. You should do that from the top-level directory of the source you downloaded and unpacked:

```
$ cd /path/to/source
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install
```

Comment: Right; but the "configure" executable does not exist.

Comment: 1) Did you unpack the source tarfile? 2) Does it have a configure script? Do the directions say it should?

Answer (score 0):

"`./configure`" means "run the program `configure` from the current directory". That is, you need to `cd` to the directory that `configure` lives in before attempting to run it like that.

As for *where* `configure` might be found, it's usually at the root of whatever source package you're trying to build.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Solaris guy, but the configure script should be within your current directory before you execute it. I am assuming you're trying to build something. If it's a project of your own, take a look at [GNU autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/). (I have no idea if this a part of Solaris or not.) It's part of M4.

If it's a project that you downloaded, untar/unzip/unpack it and then `cd` to its directory before running the configure script.